# Angularjs recorrer hijos de arbol recursivamente y mostrarlos por columnas en una tabla

Tags: angularjs

Partiendo del siguiente arreglo de objetos, como le podria hacer para formar una tabla, situando el primer padre al inicio de una columna e ir agregando los hijos en la siguiente utilizando angularjs.

Como ejemplo:

Teniendo el siguiente arreglo:

```
$scope.arreglo = [
    {
        nombre: 'Jose',
        edad: 70,
        hijos: [
            {
                nombre: 'Salvador',
                edad: 45,
                hijos: [
                    {
                        nombre: 'Rosa',
                        edad: 23,
                        hijos: []
                    }
                ]
            },{
                nombre: 'Ernesto',
                edad: 39,
                hijos: [
                    {
                        nombre: 'Paloma',
                        edad: 20,
                        hijos: []
                    },{
                        nombre: 'Fernando',
                        edad: 16,
                        hijos: []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },{
        nombre: 'Crispin',
        edad: 65,
        hijos: [
            {
                nombre: 'Ignacio',
                edad: 30,
                hijos: []
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

y convertirlo a esta tabla:

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| 1       | 2        | 3        |
+---------+----------+----------+
|   Jose  | Salvador | Rosa     |
|         +----------+----------+
|         | Ernesto  | Paloma   |
|         |          +----------+
|         |          | Fernando |
+---------+----------+----------+
| Crispin | Ignacio  |          |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

Estuve investigando y me encontre un con un metodo recursivo utilizando la directiva `ng-include` pero en listas (`<ul>, <li>`):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661289/how-can-i-make-recursive-templates-in-angularjs-when-using-nested-objects

Intente realizarlo con tablas pero solo consegui insertar las siguientes columnas dentro de la misma columna.

Answer (score 1):

Ten en cuenta una cosa, para realizar eso lo correcto será usar ng-repeat dentro de otro. Por ejemplo podría ser así:

```
<ul ng-repeat="abuelo in arreglo">
    <li> {{ abuelo.nombre }} </li>
    <li>
        <ul ng-repeat="padre in abuelo.hijos">
           <li> {{ padre.nombre }} </li> 
           <li>
               <ul ng-repeat="hijo in padre.hijos">
                   <li> {{ hijo.nombre }} </li>  
               </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```